# Using SharedPreferences only saves one marker and not the image that goes with that marker

Tags: android, google-maps

Okay so I have now implemented the `sharedPreferences` for my map to save all the markers added to the map,  However it only seems to save one marker?  Also the marker has an image to it so when tapping the marker the image is displayed, that also doesn't save.

So i basically end up with one marker saved with no data and the rest of the markers are discarded.

Can some one please point me in the right direction?

Here is when i add the marker:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(thePoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));
markerId = marker.getId();

prefs.edit().putString("Lat",String.valueOf(point.latitude)).commit();
prefs.edit().putString("Lng",String.valueOf(point.longitude)).commit();
```

and then this is when i retrieve the marker when the activity starts again:

```
String lat = prefs.getString("Lat","");
String lng = prefs.getString("Lng","");
LatLng l =new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(l).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));
```

For the `markerId` that goes by the `custonInfoWindow` :

```
View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
final ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);
Bitmap bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

So to sum up:

1. Only marker is saved and not multiple markers
2. The images that goes with that marker isn't saved as well

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my updated code:

```
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
 googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());

 prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("LatLng",MODE_PRIVATE);
 if((prefs.contains("Lat_")) && (prefs.contains("Lng_")))
 {   
 String markersfromprefs = prefs.getString("markers", null);
 String [] markerIds = markersfromprefs.split(",");

 for(String markerId : markerIds){
 String lat = prefs.getString("Lat_"+markerId,"");
 String lng = prefs.getString("Lng_"+markerId,"");
 LatLng l =new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(l).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
         .fromResource(R.drawable.sighting_marker)));
  }
 }
```

And then when adding the marker:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
thePoint=point;

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(thePoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
         .fromResource(R.drawable.sighting_marker)));
markerId = marker.getId();

prefs.edit().putString("Lat_"+markerId,String.valueOf(point.latitude)).commit();
prefs.edit().putString("Lng_"+markerId,String.valueOf(point.longitude)).commit();
prefs.edit().putString("image_"+markerId,"bitmap").commit();
String markersfromprefs = prefs.getString("markers", null);
prefs.edit().putString("markers", markersfromprefs+","+markerId).commit();
```

Comment: Please remember to accept answers. Stackoverflow is not a simple forum. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save arrays in the shared preferences or at least you have to write your own code to do it. The preference is a couple key - value so you have to use several keys to save an array. In this case you have to use a database instead of using the shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks.  Like SQlite?  And would you have an example of that?

Comment: @Allrounder http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: @Allrounder : here is an [example of using sqlite database](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/)

Comment: @greywolf82 will the edited code work, or is a database the best option? the code doesn't seem to save the markers added?

Comment: @Allrounder With the preferences is a complete mess IMHO. It's really difficult to read and to maintain. Please use a database to store positional information and the URI of the images related with the markers or any other information.

Comment: @greywolf82 Thanks I think i will have to do that then,  But to be completely honest i have never done that and looking through these links provided makes no sense to me without someone explaining to me what to do and how to implement that in what i want to achieve. Isn't there a tutorial with something similar to what i want to do?  so i can understand what each line of code does?

Comment: @greywolf82 I have found this (http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in-sqlite-from-google-maps-android-api-v2/)  will that work for what i want to achieve?

Comment: @greywolf82, Just want to say thank you so much!!  it is saving the markers to the map now,  I am not to sure though how i am going to save that specific image to that marker though.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Shared prferences stores your values as a key value pair.
What you are doing with the line

```
prefs.edit().putString("Lat",String.valueOf(point.latitude)).commit();
```

is saying to the system "Store me a String with the value of point.latitude and reference it so I can find it later with the key 'Lat'".
If you want to use shared preferences you will need to store the points with unique keys. At the moment you are overwriting the values referenced by the keys "Lat" & "Lng" for each point on your map.

One option open to you is to store all points in an array and the to store this array in preferences as a Json.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(thePoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));
markerId = marker.getId();

//markerId is added to the name of sharedPreferences
prefs.edit().putString("Lat_"+markerId,String.valueOf(point.latitude)).commit();
prefs.edit().putString("Lng_"+markerId,String.valueOf(point.longitude)).commit();
```

For the custom images, same thing:

```
prefs.edit().putString("image_"+markerId,"your_image_reference").commit();
```

Then you only have to store each marker Id (in a String, separated by a comma for example)

```
String markersfromprefs = prefs.getString("markers", null);
prefs.edit().putString("markers", markersfromprefs+","+markerId).commit();
```

To retrieve all markers coordinates:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());

 prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("LatLng",MODE_PRIVATE);

String markersfromprefs = prefs.getString("markers", null);

if (markersfromprefs != null){
    String [] markerIds = markersfromprefs.split(",");

    for(String markerId : markersId){
        String lat = prefs.getString("Lat_"+markerId,"");
        String lng = prefs.getString("Lng_"+markerId,"");
        LatLng l =new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(l).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you so much,  I do appreciate it the code and the explanations!  It all makes sense but it isn't saving any markers added now?  I have updated my question with the code provided by you.

Comment: I think the markers are added but this line:
    if((prefs.contains("Lat_")) && (prefs.contains("Lng_")))
will never be true as your prefs contains "Lat_2345" for example, not just "Lat_"

Comment: Okay i see,  but if i remove that then the app crashes with a `NullPointerException  and if I add `if((prefs.contains("Lat_"+markerId)) && (prefs.contains("Lng_"+markerId)))`  it still doesn't seem to save the markers.

Comment: Try to check if markersfromprefs != null before trying to split it and adding your points.

Comment: Okay so I have added `private String markersfromprefs;`  and then added `prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("LatLng",MODE_PRIVATE);
                if((prefs.contains("Lat_"+markerId) && (prefs.contains("Lng_"+markerId))));
                 if(markersfromprefs !=null)
                {   
                markersfromprefs = prefs.getString("markers", null);`  but still doesn't seem to save the markers.  Did i do it right?

Comment: Shall i post my whole code so you can have a look at it?

Comment: Okay sorry just saw you updated your answer,  have tried that as well but with now luck,  Its probably saving the markers but something is preventing it to load the markers when the activity starts again?

Comment: Yes I've updated my answer, sadly I can't test the code for now. What you could do is add some Logs to check the values of markersfromprefs, lat, lon... to help you detect the problem.